# Iterate a function for each column needed from Excel dataframe

Tags: python, function

I have script below that I'd like to read from a list that determines what columns to print, then merge PDF files using the data in the rows below said column.

My `model_types` list has elements like [model1], [mode2] and the dataframe looks like this:

```
   model1      model2    model3     
0  File1.pdf   File3.pdf File2.pdf
1  File2.pdf   nan.pdf   File2.pdf
2  File3.pdf   nan.pdf   File2.pdf
```

I'd like for it to read the models required from `model_types` then iterate the function for only those columns, producing each pdf document with the files from the rows in the column. model1 would have a PDF file with file1, file2 & file2where model2 would only have file3.

I get this error with the below:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'model1'

```
def merge_pdf(model_types: list[str]):
    merger = PdfFileMerger()
    for x in model_types:
        merger.append(x)
    merger.write("test{x}.pdf")
    merger.close()

merge_pdf(model_types)
```

Comment: you need to mention proper file with path

Comment: How would that look? Is that for the `merger.write`?

Comment: The error showing there is a no such file model1. means file is not present in the place which is you have mentioned.

Comment: Oh I think I'm not on the right track, I'm wanting it to create a new pdf file with the file names found in the columns with the header in `model_types`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you are looping the data only column value not a row value so that only it showing model1 file not found error.

model_types is not a list it's data frame. In case if it's list means you need to convert the data frame using pandas

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger
def merge_pdf(model_types):
    merger = PdfFileMerger()
    for col_name in model_types:
        for index, row in df.iterrows():
            merger.append(row[col_name])
    merger.write("test{x}.pdf")
    merger.close()

merge_pdf(model_types)
```

Comment: Getting error `No such file or directory: 'model1'. I'm trying to use the `model_types` to have the function read what columns it needs to make a PDF list from, then read down that column and append the file list into one PDF.

Comment: you want to merge the PDF or want to merge columns?

Comment: what is in the model_types had?

Comment: Merge the "file.pdf" found in the columns in df into one PDF, and one PDF file for each row. Sorry I'm very new!

Comment: `model_types` has a list of [model1], [model2].

Comment: model1 and model2 is not pdf right?

Comment: Correct, those are headings I want to produce a PDF file appending each separate PDF under the column into one. One pdf pack for each heading in `model_types`

Comment: but PDFmerger is different thing. it can be merge multiple pdf into single one.

Comment: Thats what I want to do, but to do that for each header.

Comment: I have updated my code pls check @Chaotic.Python